# What is the minimum value of A for this inequality to hold?

Tags: limits, inequality

$A(1.05^{n}$) > $10\frac{1.05^{n+1}-(n+1)(1.05)+n}{.05^{2}}$ for all $n \in N .$

What is the minimum value of A for this inequality to hold?

I think I need to take the limit but I'm not sure how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For all $n\in\mathbb{R}$?  For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?  For all sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2):

Solving for $A$ yields the equivalent inequality
$$
A > \frac{10}{.05^2} \bigg( 1.05 - \frac{(n+1)(1.05)-n}{1.05^n} \bigg).
$$
The right-hand side is always smaller than $\frac{10}{.05^2}1.05=4200$, so $A=4200$ is a valid choice. On the other hand, the limit of the right-hand as $n\to\infty$ is equal to $4200$, so no smaller value of $A$ is valid.